# activating virtualenv with direnv doesn't activate virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, direnv

I'm using direnv to source my virtualenv when I change into the directory.

```
/project
   .envrc
   /env <--- my virtualenv
```

.envrc

```
source env/bin/activate
```

When I change directory into `/project` I get the output:

```
direnv: loading .envrc
direnv: export +VIRTUAL_ENV -PS2 ~PATH
```

It prepends the env directory to my PATH environment variable so when I run `which python` and `which pip` both point to python and pip that's in my `env` directory

```
=> which python
/USER/project/env/bin/python
=> which pip
/USER/project/env/bin/pip
```

However it doesn't seem to run `source env/bin/activate` as I expect it to. I expect it to activate my virtualenv by adding the virtualenv name (env) to my CLI prompt and give access to the `deactivate` command, neither of that happens. Is there something I'm misunderstanding about how direnv and virtualenv work? I'm new to python so I'm not sure if there are existing tools to do something like this.

Answer (score 12):

I think it's important to understand how direnv works to form a proper mental model first; direnv doesn't load the `.envrc` directly in the current shell. Instead, it starts a new bash shell, executes the `.envrc` in there, records the changes in environment and exports the diff bash into the current shell.

What is happening here is that:

virtualenv is using `$PS1` to set the prompt. This is a local variable and thus not re-exported. `direnv` also filters `PS1` because it causes segfaults on the old macOS bash when it's unset.

The `deactivate()` function is not exported from the bash sub-shell as it's not an environment variable.

In practice the activation worked as you noticed. python is in the right path and running `pip` or `easy_install` is going to install things in the virtualenv. deactivation is not necessary as direnv will automatically unload the environment when `cd`-ing out of the directory.

To restore the custom prompt, there is more info available on the wiki: https://github.com/direnv/direnv/wiki/Python#restoring-the-ps1

Comment: Do you know of any tools that might do what I'm looking for? Entering/exiting the python virtualenv on directory change

Comment: Great answer... @Ephapox direnv does what you want! See: https://github.com/direnv/direnv/wiki/Python

Answer (score 8):

There is a "hidden" feature to do what you want in direnv. You have to take a look at the [toolbox](https://direnv.net/man/direnv-stdlib.1.html) that is loaded by direnv for you to use in the `.envrc` files. You can use the `layout` command with python (`layout python3`) to activate a virtualenv on entering the dir, and deactivating it when exiting the directory. It will even take care of creating the virtualenv the first time.

Also take a look at `source_up` that keep loading `.envrc` files higher in the file system. I start all my projects by creating a `.envrc` file with the following:

```
layout python3
source_up
```

This will create, activate and deactivate a python virtualenv automatically, and keep on reading variables from higher-level `.envrc` files. Environement variables for the current project only will go in the local `.envrc`.

Comment: it got well documented in the meantime and your answer is still correct, please see https://github.com/direnv/direnv/wiki/Python